# How to separate parts of the string with a specific percent of the needed characters?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, bioinformatics

I'm trying to make a code for finding siRNAs. For now I've made a code that's just finding all possible siRNAs combinations. I also need to find the best ones, which must contain from 30% to 50% of the GC or CG nucleotides.

This program is searching for the 21 nucleotides length sequences with content of CG or GC from 30 to 50%. For now, my program just generates in one string all of the possible siRNAs with length of 21, but I need to separate the ones with needed amount of GC or CG.

Example of how my program works with K = 2, which means a length of the iRNA sequences from mRNA:

1. inputting the DNA: ATGC
2. It's converting to the mRNA by replacing T with U, so we get: AUGC
3. Making a complementary chain by the Chargaff's rule, A to U, U to A, g to C, C to G, and we get:  UACG
4. Now we have a big iRNA, and now we splitting it in all possible ways for get a siRNAs, so:
   All iRNA combinations ['UA', 'AC', 'CG']

And at the end I want to chose from them the ones that's content C+G nucleotides in range of 30-50%.

Well, there we have only CG with 100, but lets change K to 4, and lets use  a ATGCCGTA for the input.

ATCGCGTA
All iRNA combinations ['UAGC', 'AGCG', 'GCGC', 'CGCA', 'GCAU']

So, here, the right ones are - UAGC and GCAU

```
    import re

def converttostr(input_seq, seperator):
   # Join all the strings in list
   final_str = seperator.join(input_seq)
   return final_str

DNA_seq = input("")

RNA_seq  = DNA_seq.replace("T", "U")

N = RNA_seq
iRNA = (N.translate(str.maketrans({"A": "U", "G": "C", "U": "A", "C": "G"})))
iRNA_str = iRNA 

K = 21
iRNA_comb = [iRNA[i: j] for i in range(len(iRNA_str)) for j in range(i + 1, len(iRNA_str) + 1) if len(iRNA_str[i:j]) == K]
print("All iRNA combinations", iRNA_comb)

seperator = ', '
LtS = converttostr(iRNA_comb, seperator)
print("List converted to string: ", LtS)

CG = re.split(" CG |[^a-zA-Z ]+",LtS)
print("siRNA with CG founded",CG)
```

Comment: could you explain the logic, ie how the last one has between 30%-50% GC nucleotides? because 6/11 is 54.5%

Comment: The last one was just an example it's shouldn't literally be in 30-50% range.

Comment: @OrkBiotechnologist you're supposed to provide working input and output values, anyway I've provided an answer below hope it helps.

Comment: @OrkBiotechnologist please provide an input and an expected output so that we can derive the logic needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code finds how many combinations of `GC` or `CG` is in a string and filters the ones that have value between 30-50% to an output array.

I've also printed the percentages calculated for different test cases for your reference.

**Code**:

```py
import regex as re

siRNAs=['GUUUCCCTTTG', 'GCTTTUGCTUT', 'GCTUGCUTGCU', 'CGTUCGUTCGU', 'GCTUCGUTCGU', 'CGCGTUUTCGU', 'GCGCTUUTGCU',
        'GCGCGCGCTUUTGCU', 'GCGCGCGCCGCGCGTUUTGCU'  ]

def get_count(mstring, sub1, sub2):
    idxs1 = [(m.start(), m.end()) for m in re.finditer(sub1, mstring)]
    idxs2 = [(m.start(), m.end()) for m in re.finditer(sub2, mstring)]
    count = len(idxs1)
    for i2 in idxs2:
        if any([i1[0] <= i2[0] < i1[1] for i1 in idxs1]):
            continue
        count+=1
    return count


for x in siRNAs:
    print('siRNA: ', x, ' percentage: ',((get_count(x, "GC", "CG")) * 2) / len(x) * 100, '%')


output = [x for x in siRNAs if 30 <= ((get_count(x, "GC", "CG")) * 2) / len(x) * 100 <=50]
print('output: ', output)
```

**Input**:

```
['GUUUCCCTTTG', 'GCTTTUGCTUT', 'GCTUGCUTGCU', 'CGTUCGUTCGU', 'GCTUCGUTCGU', 'CGCGTUUTCGU', 'GCGCTUUTGCU', 'GCGCGCGCTUUTGCU', 'GCGCGCGCCGCGCGTUUTGCU']
```

**Output**:

```
siRNA:  GUUUCCCTTTG  percentage:  0.0 %
siRNA:  GCTTTUGCTUT  percentage:  36.36363636363637 %
siRNA:  GCTUGCUTGCU  percentage:  54.54545454545454 %
siRNA:  CGTUCGUTCGU  percentage:  54.54545454545454 %
siRNA:  GCTUCGUTCGU  percentage:  54.54545454545454 %
siRNA:  CGCGTUUTCGU  percentage:  54.54545454545454 %
siRNA:  GCGCTUUTGCU  percentage:  54.54545454545454 %
siRNA:  GCGCGCGCTUUTGCU  percentage:  66.66666666666666 %
siRNA:  GCGCGCGCCGCGCGTUUTGCU  percentage:  76.19047619047619 %

output:  ['GCTTTUGCTUT']
```

Comment: When I'm placing mine LtS variable here "siRNAs = Lts", it's not working. The same when I just tried to use input.

Comment: @OrkBiotechnologist could you provide the `Lts` variable

Comment: For example, when K = 2

Comment: input - ATGC
All iRNA combinations ['UA', 'AC', 'CG']
List converted to string:  UA, AC, CG
siRNA:  U  percentage:  0.0 %
siRNA:  A  percentage:  0.0 %
siRNA:  ,  percentage:  0.0 %
siRNA:     percentage:  0.0 %
siRNA:  A  percentage:  0.0 %
siRNA:  C  percentage:  0.0 %
siRNA:  ,  percentage:  0.0 %
siRNA:     percentage:  0.0 %
siRNA:  C  percentage:  0.0 %
siRNA:  G  percentage:  0.0 %
output:  []

[Program finished]

Comment: @OrkBiotechnologist pass iRNA_comb, because this code needs the list of strings not a string

Comment: LtS is a List to String

Comment: @OrkBiotechnologist exactly, its not a list, but a string. Isn't each sequence in iRNA_comb the value you want to process? So pass iRNA_comb not LtS

Comment: Many, thanks everything seems to be working, but I get strange outputs with 100%, when they're not really a 100%.https://pastebin.com/uKv1j3up

Comment: So, why UCGC and CGCU are 100%? And for now I've tried with K=4, but there's the same strange mistakes with K = 2, 21, 22 and etc.

Comment: @OrkBiotechnologist Yes I too just figured there is scenario that breaks this logic. Let me try to correct this

Comment: Many thanks dude, I've modified it and now I get what I needed. Actually not I, because I'm helping for my friend, but anyway, thank you very much.

Comment: for x in siRNAs:
    print('siRNA: ', x, ' percentage: ',((x.count("C") + x.count("G"))) / len(x) * 100, '%')

output = [x for x in siRNAs if 30 <= ((x.count("C") + x.count("G"))) / len(x) * 100 <=50]

print('output: ', output)

Comment: @OrkBiotechnologist wait that's all you wanted? I thought you needed the `G` and `C` to occur together like `GC` or `CG` to make it count. for eg your code would show 45% for GUUUCCCTTTG, there is no `GC` or `CG` in there

Comment: @OrkBiotechnologist anyway I made a custom function that counts combinations so I'll update the answer to that.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to figure out what this code does, but I couldn't)) Have you written in another language before? Just specify the input data and the output you want to receive.

Returns **true** if fits the condition (30%-50%). Then you can add it to the list or whatever.

```
def foo(seq: str) -> bool:
    """searching for the 21 nucleotides length sequences with content of CG or GC from 30 to 50%
    """
    return 30 < (seq.count("GC") * 2) / len(h) * 100 < 50
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DNA_seq = input("")

RNA_seq  = DNA_seq.replace("T", "U")

N = RNA_seq
iRNA = (N.translate(str.maketrans({"A": "U", "G": "C", "U": "A", "C": "G"})))
iRNA_str = iRNA 

K = 4
iRNA_comb = [iRNA[i: j] for i in range(len(iRNA_str)) for j in range(i + 1, len(iRNA_str) + 1) if len(iRNA_str[i:j]) == K]
print("All iRNA combinations", iRNA_comb)

siRNAs = iRNA_comb

for x in siRNAs:
    print('siRNA: ', x, ' percentage: ',((x.count("C") + x.count("G"))) / len(x) * 100, '%')

output = [x for x in siRNAs if 30 <= ((x.count("C") + x.count("G"))) / len(x) * 100 <=50]

print('output: ', output)
```